# Creating TextView for dynamically created EditText using Layout Inflater Method

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-edittext, layout-inflater

I'm self-taught and have fallen in love. This is my first android app which in theory is fairly simple.

The issue: I've been successful in dynamically creating new EditTexts with a click of a button using a layoutinflator method. My problem is being able to identify the new id's of those EditTexts, or simply retrieving the new input values from the new EditTexts that the user has created... so I can display them to their respective TextViews.

Thank you in advance. I sincerely appreciate it.

MainActivity.java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LinearLayout parentLinearLayout;
    Button button;
    TextView result;
    EditText editName;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        parentLinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.parent_linear_layout);

        editName = findViewById(R.id.editName);
        result = findViewById(R.id.textViewName);

        button = findViewById(R.id.addName);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String name = editName.getText().toString();
                result.setText(name);
            }
        });
    }

    public void onAddField(View v) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_row, null);
        parentLinearLayout.addView(rowView, parentLinearLayout.getChildCount() - 1);
    }

    public void onDelete(View v) {
        parentLinearLayout.removeView((View) v.getParent());
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent_linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_field_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="#555"
        android:onClick="onAddField"
        android:text="Add Player"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        />

    <TextView
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/textViewName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name 1"
        />

    <TextView
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/textViewName2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name 2"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editName"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/delete_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
            android:onClick="onDelete" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit" />

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_row.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/number_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/delete_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
        android:onClick="onDelete"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Still I don't clear about your problem, Can you please mention about your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to get `EditText` and `TextView` from your inflated view and add `TextChangedListener` on `EditText` and update `TextView` inside `onTextChanged`

```
public void onAddField(View v) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_row, null);

    EditText editText = rowView.findViewById(R.id.number_edit_text);
    TextView textView = rowView.findViewById(R.id.your_text_view);

    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            textView.setText(s);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    parentLinearLayout.addView(rowView, parentLinearLayout.getChildCount() - 1);
}
```

Comment: @mikerigali, have you checked that?